# Finite dimensional approximation of Donaldson theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, deformation-theory, gauge-theory

In addition to the Seiberg-Witten invariant there has been further success with "finite dimensional approximations" of the Seiberg-Witten theory: Bauer-Furuta's stable (co)homotopy invariants, and  Kronheimer's and Manolescu's homotopy invariants associated with Seiberg-Witten-Floer cohomology. Such approximations were then demonstrated by Frauenfelder on the *vortex equations* in 2 dimensions. So I naively ask:

**Is it impossible to achieve finite dimensional approximations of Donaldson's theory?** If it were possible, what are the obstacles? Is there an expected use of them that perhaps Seiberg-Witten theory wouldn't reach?

While there is an expected "equality" between the Seiberg-Witten invariants and the Donaldson invariants, there is at least one defining difference between them: lack of compactness of the moduli. I'm unsure how much this affects the finite-dimensional techniques (e.g. Kuranishi constructions) from being applied to the Yang-Mills equations. It probably makes it hard, but I wonder whether it leads to a dead-end. I'm unsure what (not) to expect, especially when there are compactifications of the moduli by Gieseker and Uhlenbeck. A glimpse at other obstacles would also be informative.